# worker queues vs. continuous deployment frameworks

Tags: python, redis, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, devops

There are many CI/CD solutions out there: http://www.devopsbookmarks.com/ci. However, looking at some buildbot examples, the [snippets](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/tutorial/fiveminutes.html) of Python code seem very similar to those created when writing, say, [workers for RQ](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/).

RQ seems fairly simple while Buildbot seems quite complex. Are the additional features of a full-blown CI/CD solution like Buildbot really worth it when it's possible to create queues and workers with a much simpler (yet not as fully featured) system like RQ?

In other words, what's the best way to frame the tradeoffs between CI/CD frameworks and worker queues?

Answer (score 2):

We use Jenkins CI and the bonus you get with these larger frameworks are:

- web interface not only for task definition, but also to review the results
- wider set of plugins for different types of tasks
- visualisation of test results
- notification of users by e-mail

We were considering doing most of the tasks, Jenkins CI is doing for us (running tests on data) by other means (like AWS Lambda), but the visual interface is the main argument to stay with Jenkins as it allows our users to see the results without a need to do these things ourself.